# WinJS app events work without calling app start()?

Tags: events, winjs

Why does my WinJS app hit breakpoints I set in onactivated and oncheckpoint even after I comment out the call to app.start at the bottom of default.js? I thought a call to start was required to queue up these events.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. As documented, commenting out `app.start` disables the events such as `onactivated` from being raised. Could you provide the code you're using to cause the problem?

Comment: Be mindful of where you set breakpoints. If you set them on the line that starts with app.onactivated = and so forth, that piece of code that assigns a handler will be executed. But the body of that handler will not be run if the event is not raised, and that won't happen unless you call app.start. In short, assigning handlers and executing handlers are two different operations.

Comment: Wow. That was bang on. Thanks KB!